# Windows XP Embedded Cloning - 2 Partitions Display

Tags: partitioning, windows-xp-embedded

This is regarding a Windows XP embedded that I need to clone a displays - Compact Flash Card and and use it in another display.

Basically, the Elevators have a display inside them. These displays are programmed. The building has around 6 elevators and has 6 displays in different elevators but three of them got damaged due to a short circuit.

Basically, what I need is the displays which are working fine has a CF - Compact Flash Card in them. I used Power ISO, Win32 disk Imager, USB Image tool. All of these tools to create an image of this CF card. An image was created - these displays run on Windows XP embedded and has other software of the elevator which is running inside this Windows XP Embedded system.

I have cloned the CF card, and it booted well on the another CF card - but I have problem. If you see the picture:

[image].

I opened up the image through Power ISO but on opening I get two - Primary FAT16 and the other is Extended FAT32. How can I copy both of these into a single CF card. On Cloning this image file to the CF card using Power ISO - it does ask me which one do you want to copy is it the Primary FAT16 or Extended FAT32. While using USB image tool it doesn't ask anything but on checking the cloned disk - it doesn't have the Extended FAT32.

While I opened the Extended FAT 32 - it has the important files for installation as shown here:

[image]

Since I am beginner, I could use some help in solving this.

Basically the display is programmed in such a way that on inserting the CF card to the display and turning on the power supply - the unit starts the usual booting screen of Windows XP embedded and a software auto starts after the boot which I feel in the Extended Partition and it runs and shows the graphical images to be shown in the display. These graphical images are programmed images which shows the elevator floors, when the elevator reach each floors, which is why I need the program in the Extended Partition also to run while carrying out the cloning.

I don't know what I am doing wrong, because after cloning of the CF card the Windows XP embedded starts up, but the on check "My computer" the extended partition is not available and also the software doesn't auto start at all - in which the display shows a normal windows screen.

Could someone help me in cloning the CF card, so that it boots Windows XP embedded and also the software too. The CF card has two partitions which I do not know how to do too.

Comment: If these devices are used to control the elevators, which is what I think you are saying, you should probably contact a professional elevator maintenance company.

Comment: We are from a professional elevator company, but usually these displays are outsourced and they come with windows xp embedded software's where thes suppliers are usually from China. The support from them is not possible, and haven't been receiving any support at all.

Comment: Woof. You should use `dd`, not some silly CD authoring tool. Or R-Studio, the free demo version will clone disks just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows dosen't really like SD cards with two partitions.

I hate to say this but its quite certainly the wrong OS for the job. Grab a linux livecd, familiarize yourself with the dd syntax and use dd to make an image of the *device* (/dev/sdX with no number).

Important obligatory warning, using DD the wrong way would quite happily wipe the contents of your card. While I'm giving you a best effort answer, *please* doublecheck the syntax. I've written this in a form that is *not* going to work if you copy paste it for that reason.

Use lsblk to locate the root device of the SD card. An easy way to do this is to run lsblk before and after

if is "input file"  of is the output file

`dd if=/dev/sda of=~/disk1.img`

Reverse to apply that to a CF card.

Comment: I am not at all a person who does know about linux, any place where I could learn on how to use the above...is there any windows tool...or something that I could use using ubuntu. I have a Ubuntu installed in a USB disk of mine, but is not much aware on how to use it.

Comment: Time to learn I guess. Ubuntu *is* linux, and these commands would work on it.

Comment: On booting from Ubuntu - I tried running ddutility but it doesnt install.

Comment: I somehow - cloned the disk

I have cloned the CF card, and it booted well on the cloned CF card - but I have problem.

The CF card has two partitions - C: and D:

If the software for the display has to run, a program is present which needs to be run from the D:.

But after cloning only C drive is shown when the cloned disk is put and the D: partition is not shown.

How can I enable the D: partition to be shown - it has the important files for installation.

Comment: dd is preinstalled on ubuntu. So I donno what you mean by 'dosen't install'.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that ...read about dd and thought I have install it... anyways I have cloned but the parititon as I mentioned above isnt appearing.